# Zk Remove event Listener from selected tab

Tags: java, zk

I have 2 tabs one is Parent tab and other is child tabs.I have created Parent tab and put listener using onClose event dynamically to it and then creating child tabs. Actually I want that when user clicks on close button of Tab, he is not able to close and get message so I put event.stopPropogation() to handle the close event. After creation of child tabs, event listener should be removed out from parent tab.But listener is not removing from parent tab. As I am using removeEventlistener but it is also not working.

First Time I am calling a method in which I am adding event listener to the parent tab.

```
 mainTab.getSelectedTab().addEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE,
                new EventListener<Event>() {
                    public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

    event.stopPropogation();
        showWarning(message);
    return;

}
                });
```

then after creating all child Tabs I have to remove this listener.I am using...

```
mainTab.getSelectedTab().removeEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE,
                    new EventListener<Event>() {
                        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {



    }
                    });
```

this listener is not working on this tab but when I open new tab (sibling of main tab) then listener is not called.

How to remove listener from current tab?

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: I believe I understand your question and will take a look at a solution. However, can you please post some example code of what you have tried. It will spur more interest and understanding from the community and you are more likely to get an answer you are happy with. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the example, that helped a lot.
The problem here was in the use of the `removeEventListener` function. The second argument of the function, an `EventListener` instance, is actually the *exact* event listener that will be removed. You can see this in the ZK source code; the `removeEventListener` function is implemented in `AbstractComponent` and [on line 2140](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zk/src/org/zkoss/zk/ui/AbstractComponent.java#L2140) it checks for a known `EventListener` which `equals` the function argument.

Here is a working fix:

```
public class Controller extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

 private static final EventListener<Event> EVENT_STOPPER = new EventListener<Event>() {
   public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
        event.stopPropagation();
        System.out.println("Stopped propagation of " + event);
   }
 };

 @Wire
 private Tabbox mainTab;

 @Override
 public void doAfterCompose(Window comp) throws Exception {
   super.doAfterCompose(comp);
   addCloseEventStopper();
 }

 @Listen(Events.ON_CLICK + " = #addTabsButton")
 public void addTabsButtonClicked() {
   removeCloseEventStopper();
   addTabs();
 }

 private void addCloseEventStopper() {
   mainTab.getSelectedTab().addEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE, EVENT_STOPPER);
 }

 private void removeCloseEventStopper() {
   mainTab.getSelectedTab().removeEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE, EVENT_STOPPER);
 }

 private void addTabs() {
   Tabs tabs = mainTab.getTabs();
   tabs.appendChild(new Tab("Tab Two"));
   tabs.appendChild(new Tab("Tab Three"));
 }

}
```

The key thing here is that the same `EventListener` instance is used in `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Note here we've used a `private` `static` `final` inner class, this is just one way to hold on to a reference to an `EventListener`. There are other ways depending on your use case.

Comment: I am doing same but it is not removing listener from maintab.getSelectedtab. 
DO you have any other Solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I've tested that code and it works fine for me. Are you sure `getSelectedTab` is returning the `Tab` you expect? (Note, real code probably wouldn't rely on `getSelectedTab` in this manner as you are adding a listener to the selected tab, and later removing from the selected tab, but the selection may well have changed.)

Comment: Thanks Benbai for your help.But I have to do same thing in java class

Comment: I think that comment was for the other answer. Regarding your problem, I do believe this is the solution you need to do what you want. This code works fine in my test example. If you have a bigger project in which you are trying to get this to work, I'd recommend paring it down to just this problem. One view and one controller, the controller being just that code above. It's possible your problem isn't exactly what you thought it was. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Sean!!!your code is working fine.I am using wrong way that's y event listener is not working for me.But now it is working fine

Comment: Great, glad you got it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can call tab.setClosable(false) to remove the 'x' (close button), if you want make a tab not closable with the 'x', you can stop the close action from client side with setWidgetOverride

a zul sample below, you can move setWidgetOverride to anywhere that you can receive instance of that tab

```
<zk>
    <tabbox>
        <tabs>
            <tab label="unclosable tab" closable="true">
                <attribute name="onCreate">
                    self.setWidgetOverride("_doCloseClick", "function(evt) { return; }");
                </attribute>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </tabbox>
</zk>
```

Comment: Tab.js at github https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/tab/Tab.js