# ZK Event listener not removed from any component using removeEventListener

Tags: java, events, zk

I am having trouble removing an event listener from tab and toolbarbutton.

I have added an eventlistener to a toolbarbutton, then after doing some saving part I can't remove the listener.

`exitButton` is a `toolbarbutton`.

Both methods are in same class.  But the first Time `exitButton` has some different logic on `onClick` event but when I save my data and call `disable()` method via `globalcommand` to remove `onClick` event listener.

```
@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
    Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
    exitButton.addEventListener("onClick", new EventListener<Event>() {

        public void onEvent(Event evt) throws Exception {
            Messagebox.show("adddingggg");
        }
    });
}

@GlobalCommand
public void disable() {
    exitButton.removeEventListener("onClick", new EventListener<Event>() {

        public void onEvent(Event evt) throws Exception {
            Messagebox.show("remocvee");
        }
    });
}
```

How can I remove the Event Listener after a save?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of ["Zk Remove event Listener from selected tab"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372849).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind, that your `EventListener` instance must return `true`,
if it is the parameter of `Object#equal` called for the former added listener.

```
EventListener evl;

@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
    Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
    exitButton.addEventListener("onClick", evl = new EventListener<Event>() {

        public void onEvent(Event evt) throws Exception {
            Messagebox.show("adddingggg");
        }
    });
}

@GlobalCommand
public void disable() {
    if(exitButton.removeEventListener("onClick", evl))
            Messagebox.show("success");
}
```

This will remove the EventListener, and show message if it was successful.
You problem was that you created a new object so it is not equal to the old one.

Comment: Thanks Nabil for your help!!It is working for me. But I am having issue in removing listener from selected tab. I am applying same logic but not working.
Can you help me out?